# How much was the final Sandpiper settlement?

Tags: better-call-saul

How much was the final sandpiper settlement amount?
I think it was around 20 million. I ask because Saul was hoping for his cut of around 20 percent.

Comment: Just a note; Saul's cut was 20% of the counsel fee; i.e. the segment of the settlement apportioned to the lawyers, not the actual plaintiffs.

Comment: And as noted in the answer below (and the attached video), the counsel fee was 1/3 of the total settlement.  So overall Jimmy stood to personally gain 1/15 of the total settlement amount;  if the final settlement totaled $20 million then his share would have been $1.33 million.

Answer (score 2):

In [Act II](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Plan_and_Execution#Act_II) of '*Plan and Execution*' (S06E07), "*Cliff announces through the conference call that a settlement agreement has been reached*".

This settlement is the "*original settlement offer ([.. which would have been] reduced by a million dollars a day if it's not accepted immediately*)", and the agreement takes place as Kim and Jimmy's—now successful—plan to force the settlement has its worst and most visible effects on Howard.

It is uncertain but likely that this original offer is the $20M that Chuck demanded from Sandpiper.

> She shows Jimmy a settlement offer presented to her by Erin Brill, his former co-worker at Davis & Main. Taken aback by the figure, Jimmy calculates that he stands to make $1.16 million from his 20% share of the settlement. [source](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Sandpiper_Crossing_class-action_lawsuit#2003)

This is from the initially calculated $17.4M settlement (you can watch Jimmy make the calculations [here](https://youtu.be/CdOt_YxFkjk?t=20)).